# AMD: what does 'dependencies' mean when its an object, not an array?

Tags: javascript, amd, js-amd

I have inherited some code with an AMD module looks like:

```
define('shared/modulename', {
    load: function(name, parentRequire, callback, config) {...}
})
```

This doesn't resemble the normal AMD syntax of an [array of dependencies as documented here](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD). The code isn't commented, and there is no explanation of why the change in syntax is needed for this module.

What does this invocation of define() actually do?

Looking at the arguments given to the load() function, they seem to be AMD internals.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the simple forms of defining AMD modules. http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define

In RequireJS you can define name-value pairs in this simple format:

```
define({foo: 'yay'})
```

And you can specify the module name in define too, which you are required to when you combine your modules. So that makes our example to:

```
define('aloha', {foo: 'yay'})
```

Now back to your code. The meaning is shallow. It defines a module called `shared/modulename`.
The `exports` of that module is an Object, which contains a method called `load`.

You can use this module like this:

```
require('shared/modulename').load(name, parentRequire, callback, config)
```

Comment: Thanks @nil. I did see the 'export an object only syntax' but I;'m still confused - I know 'load()' is run (if I add logging statements), I can't see anywhere in my own code that actually runs load(), and the values of those arguments are all requirejs internals. This makes me think 'load' might be some kind of internal require thing. Any ideas?

Comment: That will be weird... Can you make a detailed sample on jsfiddle or something.